useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. (on different files)
I've been working on a project that I need to log-in. I've been following this tutorial I found while searching for information (it's the first way of the tutorial).
However, as I would like to create the project in separate files, I couldn't follow the tutorial straightly. I have multiple files:

App.js where the app is created.
log-in.js where the log-in page is located
authoriser.js that handles the auth of the user (after pressing a button)
auth-server.js that creates a database where all the users are located

I will show the key part of each file:
App.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';


import Home from './pages/home';
import LogIn from './pages/log-in';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard';

import ProtectedRoute from './components/protected-route';
export default function App() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    if (!user || !user.token) {
      setLoggedIn(false);
      return;
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:3080/verify', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'jwt-token': user.token
      },
    })
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((r) => {
      setLoggedIn('success' === r.message);
      setUsername(user.username || '');
    });
  }, []);

  return (
      <Router>
        <userContext.Provider value={username}>
          <setUserContext.Provider value={username}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/login' element={<LogIn setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setUsername={setUsername} navigate={navigate} />} />
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoute user={username} />}>
              <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard loggedIn={loggedIn} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
          </setUserContext.Provider>
        </userContext.Provider>
      </Router>
  );
}

log-in.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LogInNavbar from "../components/navbar/login-navbar";
import Authoriser from "../components/authoriser";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function LogIn(props) {
    
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ username: "", password: "" });
    //const navigate = useNavigate();

    const onChange = (event) => {
        setFormData({...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    };
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    });

    function authoriser(){       
        console.log("Authoriser");
        Authoriser(formData, props);
        if (props.loggedIn) {
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
            props.setLoggedIn(false);
        } else {
            props.navigate('/login');
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        <div className="Navbar">
            <LogInNavbar />
        </div>
        <div className="LogIn">
        <form className="LogInForm">
                <h3>Iniciar Sesión</h3>

                <label htmlFor="username">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" name="username" value={formData.username} onChange={onChange} />

                <label htmlFor="password">Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" value={formData.password} onChange={onChange} />

                <button onClick={authoriser}>
                    Iniciar Sesión
                </button>
        </form>
        </div>
        </>
    );
}

authoriser.js
export default function Authoriser( formData, props ) {

    //const navigate = useNavigate();

    const username = formData.username;
    const password = formData.password;
    
    const user = {username: username, password: password};
    
    console.log(user);

    if (username === ''){
        window.alert("Introduzca su nombre de usuario");
        return;
    }

    if (password === ''){
        window.alert("Introduzca su contraseña");
        return;
    }
    
    checkAccountExists((accountExists) => {
        if (accountExists) proceedLoggingIn()
        else if (
            window.confirm(
                'No existe ninguna cuenta con este nombre de usuario: ' + username + '. ¿Quieres crear una nueva cuenta?'
            )
        ) {
            proceedLoggingIn();
        }
    });

    // Call the server API to check if the username ID already exists
    const checkAccountExists = (callback) => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3080/check-account', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username })
        })
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((r) => {
            callback(r?.userExists);
        });
    }
   
    // Log in a user using username and password
    const proceedLoggingIn = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3080/check-account', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
        })
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((r) => {
            if ('success' == r.message) {
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({ username, token: r.token }));
                props.setLoggedIn(true);
                props.setUsername(username);
                props.navigate('/dashboard');
            } else {
                window.alert('Wrong username or password');
            }
        })
    }
}

When I execute that code it returns multiple errors that all say useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
I will be grateful if someone can help me to solve the problem.
I have tried passing navigate as props to use them (and I think it worked as before i got an Invalid hook call error).
I do not know why I cannot use navigate at the authoriser.js file, since it drops that error. I have the theory that it is because is an event handler (as it handles the log-in click button).
I have also seen that the component must be on a Router and Routes, but it is wrapped on it.
I use to travel between pages <Link>, but in this case I do not know how to implement that case, as it does not return page elements. Maybe there is a way to call other web paths but I do not know them and how to implement them at my code.

App renders the Router and thus the routing context. Move the Router higher up the ReactTree.
In the component rendering App:
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';

...

<Router>
  </App />
</Router>

App
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import Home from './pages/home';
import LogIn from './pages/log-in';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard';

import ProtectedRoute from './components/protected-route';

export default function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    if (!user || !user.token) {
      setLoggedIn(false);
      return;
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:3080/verify', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'jwt-token': user.token
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        setLoggedIn('success' === r.message);
        setUsername(user.username || '');
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <userContext.Provider value={username}>
      <setUserContext.Provider value={setUsername}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path='/login'
            element={(
              <LogIn
                setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn}
                setUsername={setUsername}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute user={username} />}>
            <Route
              path='/dashboard'
              element={(
                <Dashboard
                  loggedIn={loggedIn}
                  setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </setUserContext.Provider>
    </userContext.Provider>
  );
}

Additional note about the context providers and props. Instead of passing username and setUsername down as props, these components should use the React context values that are provided, i.e. use the useContext hook.
Also, the navigate function should also not be "props-drilled" to the Login component. Login should use the useNavigate hook.
Login
export default function LogIn(props) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ username: "", password: "" });
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  };
    
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  });

  function authoriser() {
    console.log("Authoriser");
    Authoriser(formData, { ...props, navigate });
    if (props.loggedIn) {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      props.setLoggedIn(false);
    } else {
      navigate('/login');
    }
  }
    
  return (
    ...
  );
}

